# Controlling vertical spacing in \chapterformat when using parskip=half* options

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, koma-script, parskip

Trying to customise chapter heading, i have trouble controlling the vertical spacing between the rule and the chapter name.
I would like to use paragraph spacing instead of indentation, so i'm using the Koma options **parskip=half***

But the spacing described before is bigger than with **parskip=false** and feels weird.

How can I define \chapterformat to avoid this issue?

Here is a somewhat MWE :

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,french]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % To support LaTeX quoting style
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\KOMAoptions{%
    parskip=half*
}%
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip,innerskip=0pt]{chapter}
%\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\mdseries}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    {\parskip=0pt\par}\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
  }{\enskip}%
}

\newcommand\SectionFontStyle{\sffamily}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\SectionFontStyle}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\scshape}    % Chapter in samm capitals font

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\textbf{\KOMAScriptVersion}
\par
\Blindtext
\addchap{Chapter without number}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `innersep=-\parskip`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,french]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % To support LaTeX quoting style
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\KOMAoptions{%
    parskip=half*
}%
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,afterskip=8\baselineskip,
  innerskip=-\parskip% <- changed
]{chapter}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
  }{\enskip}%
}

\newcommand\SectionFontStyle{\sffamily}
%
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\SectionFontStyle}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\scshape}    % Chapter in samm capitals font

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\textbf{\KOMAScriptVersion}
\par
\Blindtext
\addchap{Chapter without number}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another possibility is `innerskip=0pt` and

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    \par\nobreak\vspace{-\parskip}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}%
    \rule{0.9\textwidth}{.5pt}%
    \vspace{-\parskip}% <- added
  }{\enskip}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and works for this MWE. Unfortunately I cant apply to my thesis. it compiles ok with innerskip=0pt, but errors out with innerskip=-\parskip. `! Extra \else.
\XKV@wh@list ...r \expandafter \XKV@wh@list \else 
                                                  \def #3{#6}\expandafter \e...
l.28 ...,afterskip=0pt,innerskip=-\parskip]{chapter}
                                                  
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.`
My template is much more complicated, any hint on what could trigger this?

Comment: @Snow You could add `\vspace{-\parskip}` to the redefinition of `\chapterformat`.